# 2 Corinthians 5:10 addresses the Judgment Seat of Christ. What is the result of the individuals' judgment?

Tags: terminology, eschatology

This judgment is of individual Christians and addresses their actions and attitudes during their human life. The question concerns the result of the judgment.

What will change in the believer’s future as a result of his judgment. Could this affect his position in the Millennial Kingdom?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Can you please [edit] this to explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Is this question not answered in Matthew ch25?

> <sup>**31**</sup> When the Son of man comes in his glory and all the angels with him, then he will sit on his glorious throne. <sup>**32**</sup> Before him will be gathered all the nations, and he will separate them one from another. (Matthew 25:31, 32)

That is Christ acting in judgment.

The result is outlined a little later. One group "inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of the world" (v34).

The other group is sent "into the eternal fire" (v41).

Answer (score 0):

> OP:  2 Corinthians 5:10 addresses the Judgment Seat of Christ. What is the result of the individuals' judgment?

The word "judgement seat" is bema (not to be confused with thronos shown below).  Paul also uses the word bema here.

> But why dost thou judge thy brother? or why dost thou set at nought thy brother? for we shall all stand before the judgment seat of Christ. Romans 14:10

The context is one of judging Christians.

> For it is written, As I live, saith the Lord, every knee shall bow to me, and every tongue shall confess to God. So then every one of us shall give account of himself to God. Romans 14:11-12

So, the bema seat is a meeting between Christ/God and a Christian to give account of deeds, good or bad.  What might happen there?  There is reward or not for the Christian.

> If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward. If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire. 1 Cor 3:14-15

Here is a commentary.

> 15. If. . . be burnt--if any teacher's work consist of such materials as the fire will destroy [ALFORD].
>     suffer loss--that is, forfeit the special "reward"; not that he shall lose salvation (which is altogether a free gift, not a "reward" or wages), for he remains still on the foundation ( 1Cr 3:12 2Jo 1:6 ).
>     saved; yet so as by fire--rather, "so as through fire" ( Zec 3:2 Amo 4:11 Jud 1:23 ). "Saved, yet not without fire" ( Rom 2:27 ) [BENGEL]. As a builder whose building, not the foundation, is consumed by fire, escapes, but with the loss of his work [ALFORD]; as the shipwrecked merchant, though he has lost his merchandise, is saved, though having to pass through the waves [BENGEL]; Mal 3:1, 2 4:1, give the key to explain the imagery. The "Lord suddenly coming to His temple" in flaming "fire," all the parts of the building which will not stand that fire will be consumed; the builders will escape with personal salvation, but with the loss of their work, through the midst of the conflagration [ALFORD]. Again, a distinction is recognized between minor and fundamental doctrines (if we regard the superstructure as representing the doctrines superadded to the elementary essentials); a man may err as to the former, and yet be saved, but not so as to the latter (compare Phl 3:15 ).  [Jamieson, Fausset, Brown](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/jfb/1Cr/1Cr_003.cfm?a=1065014)

The bema seat is not to be confused with the Great White Throne judgment.  The word throne is "thronos".

> When the Son of man shall come in his glory, and all the holy angels with him, then shall he sit upon the **throne** of his glory: Mat 25:31

> And I saw a great white **throne**, and him that sat on it, from whose face the earth and the heaven fled away; and there was found no place for them.  Rev 20:11

This is the place of the judgment of the dead (those not part of the Body of Christ who have been reborn).

> And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those things which were written in the books, according to their works. Rev 20:12

So, the Christian appears at the bema seat, judged on works, and suffers either loss of those works or is rewarded, yet either way, will be saved.

The dead appear at the great white throne judgment.

Comment: To clarify my question a bit more, I understand that the judgment is of believers and doesn’t affect their eternal salvation. Every judgment is a “cause,” and I’m looking for the actual effect. Does this judgment affect the believer’s position in Christ’s earthly kingdom?

Comment: Does this judgment affect the believer's position in Christ's earthly kingdom? I'd assume you are asking about after the judgment, rather than before and during the so-called 1,000 year reign?  Rev 20 speaks about reigning with Christ during that period.  I'd suggest Romans 5:7 about reigning in one's current life as king/priest and based on that the answer about 1,000 years.  Be faithful in small Mt 25:21

Answer (score -1):

There is much misinformation regarding this matter due to the erroneous doctrines of the church which has relied on scare tactics to frighten people into being good so they go to heaven. Of course no one has gone to heaven or will as God is making his throne here on earth. Rev 20,21

The second death is not given at the same time as those who inherit eternal life as another answer suggests. They are not resurrected to life again so God can kill them again.

> The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were completed Rev 20:5

After this comes the second death but again, not immediately. God is a God of saving people not killing people without good reason. If they never heard of Jesus then that is not a good reason to kill them off.

> Now if anyone builds on the foundation with gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, or straw, 13each one’s work will become evident; for the day will show it because it is to be revealed with fire, and the fire itself will test [e]the quality of each one’s work. 14If anyone’s work which he has built on it remains, he will receive a reward. 15If anyone’s work is burned up, he will suffer loss; but he himself will be saved, yet only so as through fire. 1 Cor 3

So there will be a reward for those who excel at doing God's will and overcoming this world by building a better life than what they started with in sin.

And without faith it is impossible to please God, because anyone who comes to him must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who earnestly seek him. Heb 11:6

We notice this is not a judgement of life or death - life is already given to those raised in the 1st resurrection, but they will be given a reward according to their works.